# How Do I Get a Dynamic Control's Value after Postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0, postback, dynamic-controls

I have a listview that adds controls in the ItemDataBound Event.  When the postback occurs, I cannot find the new controls.  After a bit of research, I found that ASP .NET needs these controls created every time, even after postback.  From there I moved the function to bind the ListView outside of the `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` conditional.  Now I get the dynamic controls values but the static controls I have are set to their defaults.  Here is a sample of what I am trying to accomplish:

For brevity, I left some obvious things out of this example.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="MyList" OnItemDataBound="MyList_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ProductPlaceHolder">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="StaticField" Text="DefaultText" />
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DynamicItems" runat="server" />
        </asp:PlaceHolder>           
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

and here is the codebehind:

```
protected void MyList_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs e) {
    PlaceHolder DynamicItems = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("DynamicItems");
    DynamicItems.Controls.Add(textbox);
}
```

So, like I said, if I only databind when `Page != PostBack` then I cant find my dynamic controls on postback.  If I bind every time the page  loads then my static fields get set to their default text.

Comment: Have you tried the find control feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the data binding of the ListView into the OnInit() event.

Comment: wow, this worked perfectly.  can you explain the reason behind this?  i dont understand why just moving it to page_init fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

[Very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272928/how-can-i-create-buttons-and-hook-up-events-from-postback) (instead of populating a ListView the guy is generating a set of buttons). Briefly, you'll find that you have to store the items in the list in your Viestate - than fish it out on Postback and re-populate the list.

Note that this solutions implies dropping data-binding (which you might not wanna do for others reasons).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, but the controls are created when the listview databinds.  If I bind the listview after a postback, I may get my dynamic controls, but my static controls get set to their default values.

Comment: I am suggesting to drop data-binding altogether - it is not clear from my answer, I'll edit in a minute. If you have the data source you can easily iterate and create the controls yourself.